# Copiar diretório de um servidor ssh para outro

Tags: shell, shell-script, ssh

Preciso fazer a cópia de um diretório em um servidor com um *script* `.sh` rodando em outro servidor. Li sobre o comando `scp` e vi alguns exemplos de uso, mas não descobri como eu coloco a senha do servidor que estou acessando para fazer a cópia direto no meu *script*, segue um exemplo do comando `scp`:

```
scp /path/to/file username@a:/path/to/destination
```

Não precisa ser só uma linha, pode ser mais...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 - Crie as chaves como ja informado nos comentários. Use os comandos abaixo:

```
ssh-keygen
```

- Responda as perguntas, pode teclar  para todas

2- Copie a chave para a máquina destino

```
ssh-copy-id host_ou_ip_destino
```

*Caso a máquina destino utilize um outro usuario ou porta no SSH faça a copia assim:*

```
ssh-copy-id "user@vm.local -p 2200"
```

Confirme as opções que aparecem de gravação de finger-print.

3 - Testando a autenticação com chaves.

```
ssh host_ou_ip_destino
```

4- Para copiar o diretório, apesar de enviar um tar seja mais eficiente conforme comentado no seu post pelo *Daniel Omine*, utilize:

```
scp -rp dir_origem user@vm.local:/dir_destino
```

***EDITANDO PARA GERAR TAR LOCAL***
5- Para gerar um tar local com os arquivos remotos, use:

```
ssh user@vm.local "tar -cvzf - /dir_remoto/origem/" > local.tar
```

> **Fonte:**
>  ***Copiar diretório***: https://serverfault.com/a/264598/209974
>  ***Gerar
>   e copiar chave*:**
>   https://darkstrikerd.wordpress.com/2010/05/14/usando-ssh-ou-scp-sem-senha/

Comment: Oi Celso, funcionou do jeito que vc respondeu, só mais uma dúvida, como criar o tar direto na outra máquina e puxar o tar em vez do diretorio ?

Comment: Obrigado Celso!!!!!

Comment: No exemplo que postei ali, fica mais fácil que com SCP, porque o tar é criado na máquina local direto. Não vai nem gerar um tar na máquina remota.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o [`sshpass`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass):

> sshpass is a utility designed for running ssh using the mode referred
>   to as "*keyboard-interactive*" password authentication, but in
>   non-interactive mode.

Para instalar no Ubuntu/Debian:

```
sudo apt-get install sshpass
```

No CentOS:

```
yum -y install sshpass
```

Para usá-lo, faça assim:

```
#!/bin/bash
sshpass -p "<senha>" scp -r /path/to/file user@example.com:/path/to/destination
```

A opção `-r` do [`scp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) é usada para copiar recursivamente o diretório.

Comment: não posso usar o comando sudo no servidor, ele não permite!

Comment: como eu uso a chave depois ? Faço a mesma chamada que coloquei na pergunta ? scp /path/to/file username@a:/path/to/destination

Comment: estou com a id_rsa.pub dentro da pasta /.shh/authorized_keys/, dai eu uso o comando scp /path/to/diretory username@host:/path/to/destination, na sequencia ele pede a senha e o pior é q estou colocando a senha e a tela do putty fica travada, se eu aperto enter ele desce a linha mas nada acontece, e acho q não era pra pedir a senha

Comment: sim o arquivo já está no servidor remoto! continua pedindo a senha

Comment: eu digitei a senha do servidor remoto e pressionei Enter! gerou o 3 arquivos e o .pub enviei pro servidor remoto

Comment: @A.S. Esse deve ser o problema! Digite o comando `ssh-keygen -t dsa` quando pedir senha pressione Enter duas vezes! depois envie a chave pública para o servidor remoto e faça o teste novamente!

Comment: o comando é "ssh-keygen -t dsa" ou igual do artigo q me passou "ssh-keygen -t rsa" ? Ativando o modo de debug do scp consigo ver as transações entre as chaves, mas ele diz que não encontra a rsa...

Comment: @A.S. É "rsa"....

Comment: @A.S. Tente gerar novamente as chaves, mas dessa vez não coloque senha, depois envie a chave pública para o outro servidor, isso é para dar certo..